# Is $(\{0,1\}^d)^n$ a good notation subsets of length $n$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, notation

Say I want to say ``$X$ is a set of length $d$ binary vectors, and the size of $X$ is $n$.''

I suppose I could write this as $X\in(\{0,1\}^d)^n$, but it feels a bit weird, since you might read it as $\{0,1\}^{dn}$ which is of course different.

I can also write ``Let $X\subseteq\{0,1\}^d$ be a set of size $n$'', but I would like something more concise, since I need to talk about such sets a lot.

Do you know a good notation I can use?

Comment: It conflicts wtth the ordinary meaning of $A^n$ as the set of $n$-tuples with members in $A$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Right, so you're saying that $(\{0,1\}^d)^n$ wouldn't be a set of length $n$, but a tuple.

Comment: When one is planning to use a certain notation, it is particularly important to make sure not to use notation that already has a standard meaning. The notation $A^n$ is now in general use for the set of $n$-tuples, or, closely related, the set of functions from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $A$.

Comment: I'm confused, do you not then agree that $(A^d)^n$ is a set of tuples of tuples?

Comment: I do agree, if you mean **the** set of $\dots$.

Comment: I have also seen this notation $\mathbb{R}^{a\times b}$ to mean matrices of size $a$ times $b$. Maybe that's an option. A matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ is really a tuple of tuples.